# How to make a when statement with groupMatcher on Mockito

Tags: mockito, quartz-scheduler

I'm using quartz and creating Unit Tests...

A sample of my tests is:

```
when(scheduler.getJobKeys(groupEquals(GROUP_ONE_JOB_ONE)))
    .thenReturn(SET_JOBKEY_GROUP_ONE_JOB_ONE);
```

But.. the `getJobKeys()` method receives a group matcher as parameter, and when doesn't work because `groupEquals(GROUP_ONE_JOB_ONE)` always return a different instance.

Can someone help me to match the `when()` with `groupEquals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it matter whether you have a new instance?

`groupEquals` returns a GroupMatcher, which extends `StringMatcher`, which [has a robust `equals` and `hashCode` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/matchers/StringMatcher.java#103) starting when matchers were introduced (2.0.0, March 2011) and continuing through the latest Maven release (2.2.1, Sept 2013). Mockito matches using instance `equals` by default when not using Mockito matchers, or explicitly using the `eq` Mockito matcher.

What you have should work; if it doesn't, please add additional information that can help debug the problem.

Comment: Your answer made me see an error in another part that was returning null... Thank you very much!!!